# Remove if and its block with sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I'm trying to remove a conditional block from a build file using sed but so far it didn't work.

The block that I would like to remove is every occurrence of  "if (!isFoss()) { ... }".

This an text example on which I'm working on:

```
repositories {
   google()
   if (!isFoss()) {
      maven {
         url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
         }
   }

   if (!isFoss()) {
      something {
         url 'https://anotherurl.test/public'
         }
   }

}
```

The desired output is:

```
repositories {
   google()
}
```

I tried with

```
sed '/!isFoss()/!b;:A;N;;/\n}/!{s/\n.*//;bA}'
```

but its behavior isn't reliable (often leaving the condition or the last bracket).

Comment: I got `google...` and the last `isFoss`. Please update your Q to show `uname -srv` and `sed --version`. Good luck.

Comment: Is there always 1 and only 1 `whatever { ... }` block within each `if (!isFoss()) { ... }` block? Can there be `}`s within comments or strings within the `!isFoss()` block? Are the `}`s always on a line of their own (except for blanks)?

Comment: Just `sed '/isFoss/,/^   }/d'` if the indentation of the closing curly is consistent.  But if you need to count open and close... uh, not sed.

Comment: @EdMorton yes only 1  `whatever { ... } ` and no  `}  ` in comments. 
I tried steffen solution and it seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think, there's an easy way to do that because you'd need to parse the output. If however you've been very strict when writing these "repository files", this might help:

```
$ awk 'd==0{m=0} /!isFoss()/{m=1} m==1&&/{/{d++} d==0{print} m==1&&/}/{d--}' file
repositories {
   google()


}
```

`m` is a flag indicating you've found the match. `d` increments on `{` and decrements on `}`. You'll have to review all changes though.

Comment: I tried to cover this case (and also `"}"`, so string literals) with "you would have to parse", "if you have been very strict" and "you have to review all changes".

Comment: +1 for counting brackets, -1 for hard-to-read script. One liner are hardly fit for the job, imho, because one would like to address some special cases as well (e.g. what if I'm evil and I add `{` and/or `}` in commented lines?) (e.g. what if the bracket is on a new line wrt the `if()` statement?). Questions from @Ed Morton under OP statement are solid.

Comment: This worked pretty well.
I think that it can be easily generalized for future users that will find this answer

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/if (!isFoss()) {/{:a;N;/^\(\s*\)if.*\n\1}/d;ba}' file
```

On encountering the string `if (!isFoss()) {` gather up the lines following in the pattern space until a line beginning with some spaces or none followed by  `}` and then delete the contents of the pattern space.

N.B. This relies on the closing brace being aligned with the start of the if clause.